# how to send refreshToken to the token endpoint?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0

I am using JWT Tokens with [springboot-security-jwt](https://github.com/svlada/springboot-security-jwt), that have some documentation about token generation, but none about how to send the *refreshToken* to the token endpoint: using POST? GET? packing parameters in JSON? there are an example of the JSON pack?

---

### NOTES

My endpoint can be used as localhost,  `https://localhost:8080/api/user/register`, and it is working fine... return a JSON like this,

```json
{
"refreshToken": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9......Jj3hnQuMd6Im9AJhmmxaA7ILiERqHuTUf0BYCerWe4ziggvs2PiCfB_3J2f_Gc3hOqY1IgJWJRm_LrTs1UcxwQ",
"token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9......-CWgg4srJoevN7PVKOQfsQXAE3h5ySkabUb-Q-xPsEQO18KSYXWw"
}
```

but, **how to send *refreshToken* to `api/auth/token` endpoint?**
(I not see any [clues at your article](http://www.svlada.com/jwt-token-authentication-with-spring-boot/#ajax-authentication))

Using [postman](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/) with a POST to https://localhost:8080/api/auth/token  with *body*

```json
{"refreshToken": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.......Jj3hnQuMd6Im9AJhmmxaA7ILiERqHuTUf0BYCerWe4ziggvs2PiCfB_3J2f_Gc3hOqY1IgJWJRm_LrTs1UcxwQ",
}
```

I have response

```js
{
  "errorCode": 10,
  "message": "Authentication failed",
  "status": 401,
  "timestamp": 1481753363749
}
```

---

### Perhaps other problem...

(edit with more clues about my implementation)

My configs at my equivalent [WebSecurityConfig.java](https://github.com/svlada/springboot-security-jwt/blob/master/src/main/java/com/svlada/security/config/WebSecurityConfig.java)

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
public static final String JWT_TOKEN_HEADER_PARAM = "Authorization";
public static final String FORM_BASED_LOGIN_ENTRY_POINT = "/login";
public static final String TOKEN_BASED_AUTH_ENTRY_POINT = "/auth/**";
public static final String TOKEN_REFRESH_ENTRY_POINT = "/token";
...
}

...

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

http
.csrf().disable() // We don't need CSRF for JWT based authentication
.exceptionHandling()
.authenticationEntryPoint(this.authenticationEntryPoint)

.and()
.sessionManagement()
.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)

.and()
.authorizeRequests()
.antMatchers(FORM_BASED_LOGIN_ENTRY_POINT).permitAll() // Login end-point
.antMatchers(TOKEN_REFRESH_ENTRY_POINT).permitAll() // Token refresh end-point
.and()
.authorizeRequests()
.antMatchers(TOKEN_BASED_AUTH_ENTRY_POINT).authenticated() // Protected API End-points
.and()
.addFilterBefore(buildAjaxLoginProcessingFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
.addFilterBefore(buildJwtTokenAuthenticationProcessingFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
}
```

so, perhaps (?) no endpoint `/token` exist (!) with this changes.

... **Where the [springboot-security-jwt](https://github.com/svlada/springboot-security-jwt/blob/master/src/main/java/com/svlada/security) `/token` implementation?** to check it (or a kind of "health endpoint test")...

PS: the spected endpoint "/api/token" and any other "api/Mammy" returns  405  (Method Not Allowed), and testing as authorized endpoint, "auth/token" or  "api/Mammy", returns 401 and error 10 (Authentication failed).

Comment: Send the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` value of `grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=<token_value>&redirect_uri=<redir_uri>` using a `POST` method to the Token Endpoint. If the client is confidential, you should authenticate the client using Basic Authentication

Comment: Thanks @AliDehghani! I used your test... Them see that my code perhaps have other problem... See my edited version of the question, with source code fragments.